# Pandas: Multiply previous row value with another column value to generate new row

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to find an answer to this but haven't been successful. I am new to Pandas so please point me to the right solution if this has been asked and answered.

I have the following dataframe with sales data for 2018 thru 2021. I want to replace the sales of zero in 2022 with the following calc:
sales_2022 = sales_2021 * (1 + gth_2022)
the result should be 135.42

```
    y = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2018,2019, 2020, 2021, 2022],
                "sales" : [100, 128, 99, 122, 0],
                 "gth": [0,0,0,0,0.11]})
    print(y)
```

This case highlights a simple fact that I don't understand Pandas well. I tried going through the documentation also but could not find how to move efficiently amongst rows and columns to generate new calculation based rows.

I would like to avoid loops since the df I am dealing with is large and has many categories (this is just a stylized example).

Thanks.
MG_Dev

Answer (score 0):

use Loc to identify the row to update, then using shift get previous sales value. Finally take the product

```
y.loc[y['year'].eq(2022), 'sales'] = y['sales'].shift()*y['gth'].add(1)
y
```

Alternately,

```
#choose rows there sales is zero and then calculate by multiplying gth with 
#previous years sales. instead of limiting to just 2022
y.loc[df['sales'].eq(0), 'sales'] = y['sales'].shift()*y['gth'].add(1)
y
```

```
year    sales   gth
0   2018    100.00  0.00
1   2019    128.00  0.00
2   2020    99.00   0.00
3   2021    122.00  0.00
4   2022    135.42  0.11
```

Comment: My bad: my thank you for a great explanation never made it to you. Thanks. Very helpful and works well.

Comment: Great! Accepting and upvoting is stackoverflow synonyms for thanks. Consider accepting and/upvote if you found it useful. @mg_dev